# Is it a valid Go type?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, parsing, syntax

Write the shortest program or function that will determine if an input is a valid Go type.

### Spec

This challenge will use the following simplified subset of Go types. For more information, see the [Golang specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Types).

- "Primitive" types:

  - `bool`
  - `int`,`uint`,`float(32|64)`,`complex(64|128)`,`byte`,`rune`
  - `string`
- `*T` where `T` is any type
- `[]T`, a slice of `T`
- `[n]T`, an array of `T`, and `n` is some positive non-zero integer
- `map[K]V`, where `K` and `V` are any type
- `chan T` (note the required whitespace)
- `struct{...}`, where `...` is a list of 0 or more semicolon-separated types (such as `struct{int;float64;*struct{int;bool}}`).
- `func(args)return`, a function.

  - `args` is an optional comma-separated list of types.
  - `return` is optionally either a type, or a *non-empty* list of types in parentheses `(a,b,c)`.

All truthy inputs have characters in the set `[][a-z0-9(){},;* \t\n]`. It is not guaranteed that an input that matches this regex is truthy.

Whitespace is allowed everywhere within the type, as long as it does not break apart keywords (`struct`, `chan`, `map`, `func`) or primitive types.

### Test Cases

#### Truthy

```go
bool
int
complex128
*int
*********int
[]string
[][]int
[ 10 ] [ ][123] * [567] [ ] [890 ] *rune
map[int]string
map[ []int ] [] string
map[map[map[int]string]map[bool]chan map[int]int]struct{int;string;bool}
struct{ }
struct{int; float64; *struct{int;bool} }
struct{struct{bool;struct{int; *[]chan complex128}; *float64}; map[string]string}
func()
func(int,uint,int,bool)string
func(int,uint,int,bool)(string,string,string)
func(func(int) int) func(func([]map[string]int) int) func(int) int
chan chan chan chan chan chan int
map[func() func() func()]func() func() func()
chan []string
func(int)(int)
```

#### Falsy

```go
integer   // unknown primitive
float     // unknown primitive
imaginary // unknown primitive
int*      // * with no type
[]        // missing contained type
[]asdfghjkl // unknown type
[[]]int     // [] is invalid for array length
[-1]string  // negative ints are invalid for array length
[123.456]float64     // floats are invalid for array length
struct{int,float64}  // missing semicolon between member types
func(int)(int,string // missing closing paren
struct{func(int)map[int]string // missing closing brace
structfunc(int)map[int]string} // missing opening brace, unknown type
chanint      // missing required whitespace
chan[]string // missing space whitespace
func()()     // non-empty parenthesized return type only
[0]int       // positive non-zero integers only
func(int)(int)(iint) // dangling leftovers `(iint)` is not a type
```

Comment: It would be helpful to better specify exactly where white-space should allowed, I had to guess from the test cases

Comment: @mousetail added a whitespace clarification

Comment: Would `chan[]string` be invalid because it doesn't have the required whitespace?

Comment: @DanielSchepler ah, that's technically valid go, but let's keep the required whitespace for this challenge

Comment: Is `func()()` valid or should the 2nd list be non-empty?

Comment: @Arnauld `func()()` is not valid; the return type must either be empty, 1 type, or parenthesized comma-separated list of types.

Comment: This is probably invalidating some answers. Maybe it should be clarified as "or a _non-empty_ list of types in parentheses".

Comment: Suggested testcase: `[0]int` (falsy)

Comment: @SuperStormer yeah that's falsey, i missed my own spec about positive non-zero ints for arrays

Comment: suggest false case `func(int)(int)(iint)` in case someone reuse something

Answer (score 14):

### Regex (PCRE), 241 bytes

```
^(bool|u?int|float(32|64)|complex(64|128)|byte|rune|string|&\s*(?1)|\*\s*(?1)|\[\s*\d*\s*\]\s*(?1)|map\s*\[\s*(?1)\s*\]\s*(?1)|chan (?1)|struct\s*\{\s*(|((?1);\s*)*\s*(?1)\s*;?\s*)\}|func\(\s*(((?1),\s*)*(?1),?\s*)?\)\s*(\s*(?1)|\((?6)\))?)$
```

Fixed to handle `func()()` case

[Try it on regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/vanW2f/1)

Answer (score 7):

## [BNFC](https://bnfc.readthedocs.io/) + [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 175 + 96 = 271 bytes

```
bool"
int"
uint"
float32"
float64"
complex64"
complex128"
byte"
rune"
string"
*"T
[""]"T
["Integer"]"T
map""["T"]"T
chan "T
struct""{"[T]"}"
Q
QT
Q"("[T2]")"Z2","Z";";_.T2::=T
```

Compile with

```bash
sed 's/Q/func""("[T2]")"/g;s/Z/;separator T/g'|awk '{print"A"NR".T::=\""$0";"}'>g;bnfc -m g;make
```

Produces an executable named `TestG` which accepts input from `stdin` and exits with code `0` if the parse was successfull, `1` otherwise.

Possibly can be golfed more with a better use of sed and awk.

---

Script to test it:

```bash
cat truthy falsy | sed "s|//.*||" | xargs -d "\n" -I {} sh -c 'echo "{}" | ./TestG >/dev/null ; echo $? "{}"'
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), <s>205</s> 193 bytes

```
*~~/^$(/:s \s*[bool|u?int|float[32|64]|complex[64|128]|byte|rune|string|\*<~~>|\[
\d* \]<~~>|map \[<~~>\]<~~>|chan\s+<~~>|struct \{ <~~>*%\; \}|func \(<~~>*%\,\)[<~~>|
\( <~~>*%\, \) ]?]\s*/)$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJtU@JADP7ur8g4eLRrlQOxp/ZOfshujqnYIh60TF9mjmHLX8fNvtBWhZnuJk@ehOTZbJNiHR43O/iRwp8jOxxGfwfe6KkEUTL@kudrWc9WWSXTdR5X/G4iwynKRb7ZrpP/PJzK8eQB5cuuSmRRZ4ksq2KVLaVgvw@HZyn4hXhlIFB7m3gLgpNpgcVbnInyWtsqsV5UIPZALrsSEYhGpnW2AOFZKBC@TpcXwnO0AIQPOEPV7sgfjI4RlPEOLvez1BvM/eYJBvNLSPMChjTMMIChmoYuO4PqnzxmUeZ@1udoJjI2RwfD@CcgcEA@ntwhMOD34S8NAH94pBgjPYirxuYqrVOIENC1iI7Qj7ivzUFyqX0kxcAFLUHJtldmZLgR8RqqZUPQdYgH@inDaQSsg@q0HtdeFIi66YybNloBGwXaosqk9mzf5tJF6SU9/2SpSkFNB330F34rwhmCZxhB72oruiwf9NFiHDsdfSI4Vy@EHurcYUlUyowCvQu/A@22Jcuk0G2SRBrbxMtVFhc7S2Bmu8wZl6/p8u39n95VzvG0cjfj7i6qtbud3odode@/ceBeoyunrzVtS1j6Kfx1Tw3jDKFxmlF/xw8)

This is an anonymous function that matches its argument against the giant regex following the leftmost `~~`.  That regex is of the form

```
/^$(/.../)$/
```

It interpolates the inner regex `$(/.../)` into the outer one.  The outer regex requires that the overall match be anchored at the beginning and end of the string.

The inner regex matches a Go type.  It is recursive, calling itself using the expression `<~~>`.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 250 bytes

*Thanks to [@Bbrk24](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/106545/bbrk24) and [@Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink) for reporting bugs*

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
f=(s,t)=>s!=(s=s[R='replace'](T='T',t)[R](/chan |\[([1-9]\d*)?\]|map\[T\]/g,'*')[R](/\w \w/)[R](/ /,'')[R](/bool|u?int|float(32|64)|complex(64|128)|byte|rune|string|\*T|struct{(T(;T)*)?}|func\((T(,T)*)?\)(T|\(T(,T)*\)|(?=[,;})\]])|$)/,T))?f(s,T):s==T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVXbctowEH3nK7aZztjyOKEkKb0wbp7aD@j4TdaDMQKUGsmV5FBa8@2pLsYYGpMyY0va3XO82huP@VOuCskqfc3Fgj4/L5NQxRolX9Qbs0sU/p4EklZlXtCAhGkSpIFR4@8kHBfrnEOT4RBPrj@RbBGhh4w0m7zKcJqR8SoOosBbZlvItmO/h3EctOK5EGVTPzCum2Upch3e3TbTe9QUYlOV9Fc4vW8mtx9RM99p2sia00ZpyfiqyaLUbutC/wnTcJYi8@l9s6x5kYVGEDtBhsK0ydpjhprwIcHxbI8yQlDzFo2NGD0szW1T9FklSfpcCK5ESW9KsQoDnMpar3ckQLMRHgFcWWevYrsz/vpN66fx0Z@jThMdfp0EE@/74YTJUQWTd0AAA8GT2zsCEeD30w9OAPjjJ6uL7O29tYkvNtATOisDx2ghBM51h@eII/Zor0RcFg/K1sAG1mxn3nZm7faerVXC6dHagkvh9H4GUU/qoGfW7WJVsz5BhL0zx7DujbClNVvrZOu9X1pam/cQ9faGLa7tyz72M6gfkAGT0NvEJ0uf9YBD4F5HGSY9z84MDse2YNz1hl6dmaXzl4KThbwkPPcQxe3ShtafZn7Zo6sRGd0shfyaF@tQQfIF@mVv2gEhU/Gjk17IOP6Wl6rXDMZVuqLyKoaB33gMNf/BxZZDJdmGafZEnZ82m8OwYSDb5CvGc7kbAg8CuY4ufdACI9gyvQYuQO8q6hv0IsahNkwpk3IbQJ0zThc9dK4Wy9X68Uf5Mk3P2Q6DiR8JF75oWpspUydPeckWYLIIuZT5DkrKV3rtWK4n3WQYYuF0ldvo2IJThoFeZjQz6eb@/ZS0jfgPr2F0qtepjs0eH7r6lK0XVEU3rBCl4DCnekupmVF0M6fSxUv1@xi5Zn7h0v0UlcKtlXGR91zpOM6n6kvguTR/gkfwAHZ/ChYV5R04/ifrtvFfy/qBStKfNZOmzLZrpqmqWm8sBb6U9H5ULegM7yeDHSTDLnDBr@mm0jsfQb2miv02nkiqa@lvA4KXO1cw7y7XseWrTERdCVri31QKaCeK6mjMhaCb2el/ja3nvw)

#### How?

At each iteration:

- If we find a `"T"` and this is the first iteration, we replace it with `"undefined"` to invalidate the input.
- We replace all occurrences of `/chan /`, `/\[([1-9]\d*)?\]/` and `/map\[T\]/` with `"*"`. They all boil down to a valid prefix of another type.
- If we find `/\w \w/`, we replace it with `"undefined"` to invalidate the input.
- If we find a space somewhere else, we remove it.
- We then look for the first valid type and replace it with `"T"`:

  - primitive types: `/bool|u?int|float(32|64)|complex(64|128)|byte|rune|string/`
  - a type preceded with `*`: `/\*T/`
  - a `struct` type: `/struct{(T(;T)*)?}/`
  - a `func` type: `/func\((T(,T)*)?\)(T|\(T(,T)*\)|(?=[,;})\]])|$)/`

The `func` type is the trickiest one because we must not ignore a *return* statement that is not yet fully simplified. That's why we make sure that `func(...)` is followed by either a valid *return* statement or the end of the line or one of `,;}]`.

This process is repeated recursively until there's nothing more to replace. If the input string is valid, we should end up with a single `"T"`.

#### Example 1

```go
func(int,uint,int,bool)(string,string,string)
func(T,uint,int,bool)(string,string,string)
func(T,T,int,bool)(string,string,string)
func(T,T,T,bool)(string,string,string)
func(T,T,T,T)(string,string,string)
func(T,T,T,T)(T,string,string)
func(T,T,T,T)(T,T,string)
func(T,T,T,T)(T,T,T)
T
```

#### Example 2

```go
map[map[map[int]string]map[bool]chan map[int]int]struct{int;string;bool}
map[map[map[T]string]map[bool]*map[int]int]struct{int;string;bool}
map[map[*T]map[bool]*map[int]int]struct{int;string;bool}
map[map[T]map[bool]*map[int]int]struct{int;string;bool}
map[*map[T]*map[int]int]struct{int;string;bool}
map[***map[T]int]struct{int;string;bool}
map[****T]struct{int;string;bool}
map[***T]struct{int;string;bool}
map[**T]struct{int;string;bool}
map[*T]struct{int;string;bool}
map[T]struct{int;string;bool}
*struct{T;string;bool}
*struct{T;T;bool}
*struct{T;T;T}
*T
T
```

Comment: This erroneously accepts `[0]int`.

Comment: This accepts `T`, which I'm pretty sure isn't a valid type.

Comment: Also, stuff like `i nt` are also accepted.

Comment: @ValueInk Seems like I misinterpreted _valid input_ as _input_ in the last two rules of the challenge. :-/

Comment: @ValueInk It should now be fixed. Thank you for reporting this.

Comment: You need to include `f=`

Comment: Is it shorter to reject `*[\s` than accept `,;}]`?

Comment: @l4m2 I think we'd need `(?![*[ (\w])`, which is the same length.

Answer (score 4):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>1279</s> 1277 bytes

```go
import(."regexp";."strings";U"unicode")
func P(s string)(string,bool){S,M,C,t,Z:=U.IsSpace,MustCompile,CutPrefix,0,0<1
T,X:=func(){for len(s)>0&&S(rune(s[0])){s=TrimSpace(s[1:])}},!Z
N:=func(){T();s=s[1:];T()}
T()
if len(s)<1{return s,X}
if k:=M(`^(bool|u?int|float(32|64)|complex(64|128)|byte|rune|string)($|[]});,\s])`).FindStringIndex(s);k!=nil&&k[0]<1{s=s[k[1]-1:];T();return s,Z}
if s[0]=='*'{return P(s[1:])}
if s[0]=='['{N();k:=M("^[1-9][0-9]+").FindStringIndex(s);if k!=nil{s=s[k[1]:];N();return P(s)};N();return P(s)}
if r,o:=C(s,"map");o{s=r;N();s,o=P(s);if!o{return s,X};if s[0]==']'{N()};return P(s)}
if r,o:=C(s,"chan");o{s=r;if!S(rune(s[0])){return s,X};T();return P(s)}
if r,o:=C(s,"struct");o{s=r;T();if s[0]!='{'{return s,X};N();for s[0]!='}'{s,o=P(s);if!o{return s,X};if s[0]=='}'{break};if s[0]!=';'{return s,X};N()};N();return s,Z}
if r,o:=C(s,"func");o{s=r;T();if s[0]!='('{return s,X};N();for s[0]!=')'{s,o=P(s);if!o{return s,X};if s[0]==')'{break};if s[0]!=','{return s,X};N()};N();if len(s)<1||M(`^[]});,\s]`).MatchString(s){return s,Z}
if s[0]=='('{N();for s[0]!=')'{s,o=P(s);if!o{return s,X};t++;if s[0]==')'{break};if s[0]!=','{return s,X};N()};if t<1{return s,X};N()}
if M(`^[iufcmbrsc*[]`).MatchString(s){return P(s)};return s,len(s)<1}
return s,X}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vVbNbuM2EL70Yj0FLXRj0mEMO5t1s9aqPQRYYA8JDDgLLKJoG0WRHNWy5IoUkEDSk_QSLLDv0GfpY_ReoDPUj2XHDoIealgkNTP8-HH-7D--zeOnP1eOu3DmHlk6QaQFy1WcSN1fSv17Kv2j079--KeU0YGeeHPvYaUbA13IJIjmQjc-62kUuPGdpzPNTyOXTKkgpZbRcua3cRyybMbP-RmX_Gpifh58EjM41uPnqZBn8XIVhB4_S-U08fzggQ_58MNIu-RfJiZiUpb5cUJCL6KC_Tw8OJjRJI08KqyhzVgmzMskWCo8EI0mNisK3r3SLprdl5QZwlQ6A9aFBoMW-BXih1GWeDJNIiL4lwLli4l5Tm--UiSep78Ekcz9MHYkfXucj09Y7gLj0Hug45N8dHzK8ttH6eVIKa9v_mNu2QUz-LWw2Q0bfAyiu5lSfYruYKNgxqJrRkF4cLCASwADpLewRvZRxdFoKF0pSnhX0-z1ezXXaX3XltbqZRewVdHXv1qjo_e2NYThUN9JAW-qWDSnw9kX67PhCFY8E-B5CY8n5hkVXF86K50ZMSAkylLw2JyW4N247VdjTdNWNIsXUN17J2pgAWkz4G3UyxfZQThSVzZIaFzR6Jq9rLeBhOwxzSpt0ctecxcwu008Z1G0gI1nwBterEO6polpuockfZEkex1JtoMk30OyVRZ5jlXQJDLk8bkj3fsyi8Ai252jtMzC19KUh4f_gSpo5WbhKjnSUKSD1HeXt4lw-9Z-4mWCNxj1vQutBVt3wb9Vd8MeSRnJtA5klrx_JBOTzFZhIOmN6jXQKniKAz6q79VNcGMqeyWttzCihrXMsqGurNLW3jKoXzUsErJ3QAsEKVsg2ZjsXUIN6WoKuGxv0Nq0Pr736w--WHZJCxaWrQRkNCQ2sYhtjY7f2qRPrHfjn5SAWKfvUdfH6lVsYEO9H1-JgkBDm7TE9bO2Vv5Agra6XK2sDKDGM1gapa2BdoVWyUmzQgui-vj4xCD9llRtWBtWE0qN9l5IpdK_jX8KEFaIsGzFrJwKrXLtntyortyEVQ03nOjX0P00reM7ofB25ZiyrHKpZt3otvxcqvdoC5VFdTY1sS1pA3EoQFTCAz_9iabuCv8RnHkQOckjyvuQCPB1xJ0_v_9tEWqWZZd5cTRqUgUSY3DybmxXvmpFhNfu2_ICDbZ9sZSDKaDJMKK6acJvPtYfLEDbwV7zKycSXZU4EfyZqcoTCrUjOIlRMaUSTDvQIbqxUqwxfaoHkRsniefKCXkjriMCH0eSN7_D8QDMicC9BfEgIlubkVC80JVew29bw54z_6iiupd5FfTdzP9P4lXre3oq538B)

An *extremely* straight-forward recursive solution. The parser makes use of the fact that Go types are mainly right-recursive, with an unambiguous prefix determining the parser state.

Most definitely can be golfed down by using a different algorithm, or making it iterative.

(Fun fact: the builtin `go/parser` package fails some test cases due to the recursive anonymous `struct`s. It expects typenames or field names there. Though, in normal usage with gofmt, nested anonymous structs tends to not happen.)

- -2 bytes: account for "dangling" leftovers, move true/false into variables (@The Thonnu)

#### Ungolfed

```go
func parse(s string) (string, bool) {
    trimSpace := func() {
        for len(s) > 0 && unicode.IsSpace(rune(s[0])) {
            s = strings.TrimSpace(s[1:])
        }
    }
    nextChar := func() {
        trimSpace()
        s = s[1:]
        trimSpace()
    }
    trimSpace()
    // false on empty
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return s, false
    }
    // primitive types
    if k := regexp.MustCompile(`^(bool|u?int|float(32|64)|complex(64|128)|byte|rune|string)($|[]});,\s])`).FindStringIndex(s); k != nil && k[0] < 1 {
        s = s[k[1]-1:]
        trimSpace()
        return s, true
    }
    // pointer
    if s[0] == '*' {
        return parse(s[1:])
    }
    // slice/array
    if s[0] == '[' {
        nextChar()
        // look for a positive int
        k := regexp.MustCompile("^[1-9][0-9]+").FindStringIndex(s)
        if k != nil {
            s = s[k[1]:]
            nextChar()
            return parse(s)
        }
        nextChar()
        // contained type
        return parse(s)
    }
    // maps
    if rest, ok := strings.CutPrefix(s, "map"); ok {
        s = rest
        nextChar()
        // key
        s, ok = parse(s)
        if !ok {
            return s, false
        }
        // account for primitive
        if s[0] == ']' {
            nextChar()
        }
        // value
        return parse(s)

    }
    // chan
    if rest, ok := strings.CutPrefix(s, "chan"); ok {
        s = rest
        // required space
        if !unicode.IsSpace(rune(s[0])) {
            return s, false
        }
        trimSpace()
        // contained type
        return parse(s)
    }
    // struct
    if rest, ok := strings.CutPrefix(s, "struct"); ok {
        s = rest
        trimSpace()
        if s[0] != '{' {
            return s, false
        }
        nextChar()
        // semicolon-separated list of types
        for s[0] != '}' {
            // type
            s, ok = parse(s)
            if !ok {
                return s, false
            }
            // when 1 type, next is a '}'
            if s[0] == '}' {
                break
            }
            // semicolon
            if s[0] != ';' {
                return s, false
            }
            nextChar()
        }
        nextChar()
        return s, true
    }
    // func
    if rest, ok := strings.CutPrefix(s, "func"); ok {
        s = rest
        trimSpace()
        // comma-separated args
        if s[0] != '(' {
            return s, false
        }
        nextChar()
        for s[0] != ')' {
            // type
            s, ok = parse(s)
            if !ok {
                return s, false
            }
            // when 1 type, next is a ')'
            if s[0] == ')' {
                break
            }
            // comma
            if s[0] != ',' {
                return s, false
            }
            nextChar()
        }
        nextChar()
        // return type
        // can be nothing, 1 type, or parened comma-separated types
        // nothing
        if len(s) == 0 || regexp.MustCompile(`^[]});,\s]`).MatchString(s) {
            return s, true
        }
        // multiple types
        if s[0] == '(' {
            nextChar()
            typeCount := 0
            for s[0] != ')' {
                // type
                s, ok = parse(s)
                if !ok {
                    return s, false
                }
                typeCount++
                // when 1 type, next is a ')'
                if s[0] == ')' {
                    // nextChar()
                    break
                }
                // comma
                if s[0] != ',' {
                    return s, false
                }
                nextChar()
            }
            // no non-empty paren return type
            if typeCount == 0 {
                return s, false
            }
            nextChar()
        }
        // 1 type
        if regexp.MustCompile(`^[iufcmbrsc*[]`).MatchString(s) {
            return parse(s)
        }
        return s, len(s) == 0
    }
    return s, false
}
```

Comment: You could save 24 bytes by assigning `0>1` and `0<1` to variables and then using them in your return statements. [Attempt This Online!](https://tinyurl.com/ThonnuGolfingSuggestion)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, <s>239</s> 234 bytes

Uses the replacement strategy from Arnauld's [Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263881/52194) as a full program using the `-nl` flag to loop the code over each line of input. Since Ruby doesn't let you inject `undefined` by leaving out arguments, the relevant replacements to force disqualification use `X` instead.

I had a slightly different regex strategy for solving the `func` issue but it turns out using the regexes from that answer was shorter.

```ruby
sub'T',?X
1until$_==(gsub /\[([1-9]\d*)?\]|map\[T\]|chan\s/,?*;sub /\w\s\w/,?X;sub /\s/,'';sub /bool|u?int|float(32|64)|complex(64|128)|byte|rune|string|\*T|struct{(T(;T)*)?}|func\((T(,T)*)?\)(T|\(T(,T)*\)|(?=[,;})\]])|$)/,?T)
p$_==?T
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVNdbtpAEH7oU32KUYTErmWamBBKZCFfwg-RdleRIYaQGoPAVoq6Pklf-pCqZ2qP0FN0Zn8wVMGSd2e--Wb8zez6-9uumR1-iatBVV6pty30Hn829WIw-f1338z6WT9KH4K4qepV2XucTtkSUbiWgol4cK_kU8hTqfQ630qRoTF_ziu5v47SMLHEV7mXr-g_OB9j_b61Z5tNqZt0VdV6UW7ymt0O9XjE9Xyz3pbFVzYe6Xg44Xp2qAu9a6pC7-vdqlpqGWZkNvP6G8tYknEU0epFU80lQyAygOQs09K5kmuWTkWUtFwqxXWPo6SMB1vqKc1sxz_c9ufDgqQFKCxwWlBHEJIf-occoawgNIQyAMQ3oD4KUCIe3ioIQdyNPytAAMTkHmMQUiMBzktggs8nF0wJIio4gf3bsRW5JFDRsMEHHYGGgmZiuQnx2sDhcLSIAWbo41EC4QlqEjqi2whNTnNDYb_ezadF0FVEk1Q5uXZrAzofxu2GNaKGFnqpOHctX4gyG47ONlfLp3AwS4cJdaLiP4J3A9vFpYUYVMRqh7NNvQfaeseLgfnFstgBQGBmA2St1vlyVeW7A1A8NBgeun3QyvdPi-Xzy5cSHaHMrbCRQezqkoMX7NPobqzczC2lO6LInwV92ndsJutKeO4xeH7LfPxCuAXTqddmPXHMtcPAqZDSG9XRMiprTOTZ_-0f)

Comment: @Arnauld thanks. I had a substitution at the beginning at first but it was erroneously "optimized" out.